# How to make this nested for loop function correctly

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create this differential calculator and when I go to calculate the the monthly payment and insert the month count into the format string, it keeps creating a repeat per each month and not creating successive month payments, or it just makes the code not output anything. I really want to figure this out on my own, so if anyone could point me in the right direction for this that would be great. Thanks in advance!

```
def diff_calc():
    # create alias for all parsed arguments for cleaner code

    loan_type = args.type
    payment = args.payment
    principal = args.Principal
    periods = args.periods
    interest = args.interest

    if args.interest is None:
        interest = 10
    if args.Principal is None:
        principal = 1000000
    if args.periods is None:
        periods = 10

    i = (interest / (12 * 100))
    overpayment = (principal * i)
    for m in range(1, periods + 1, 1):
        while m <= periods:
            Dm = ((principal / periods) + i * (principal - (principal * (m - 1)) / periods))
            print(f'Month {m}: payment is {Dm}')
```

Comment: If you want to figure this out on your own you shouldn't publicly ask a question about it. - Speaking of which, what exactly *is* the question?

Comment: Your while loop is infinite coz you are not modifying m or periods

Comment: I just want a pointer on how I would nest this correctly. I feel like it has to do with either a for loop or while loop

Comment: The for loop is doing what your while loop is trying to do. So remove while loop and see if it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like no one provided you a response.

remove the while loop as it is doing the same thing as for loop. The while loop is not incrementing `m` and resulting in an infinite loop situation. By eliminating this, the for loop will take care of the processing.

The change in your code has to be:

```
for m in range(1, periods + 1, 1):
    #while m <= periods: #remove this line as it is redundant
        Dm = ((principal / periods) + i * (principal - (principal * (m - 1)) / periods))
        print(f'Month {m}: payment is {Dm}')
```